# Is there way to remove strips and categories gaps for JavaFX BarChart

Tags: java, javafx, bar-chart

I very like the new Java FX charts module but I do not understand how to fix the following bug/feature. 
When I have BarChart with many categories - it's showing strips instead of showing solid color. I already set-up

```
        myBarChart.setBarGap(0);
        myBarChart.setCategoryGap(0);
        myBarChart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Please advise.

Comment: This just looks like an aliasing-like effect. Wouldn't an [`AreaChart`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/AreaChart.html) be better here anyway?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the default color within caspian.css (css file for JavaFX nodes), I can see there is currently a color assigned to the background of the bars which has a gradient. I think this is an illusion that you are seeing after setting `myBarChart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false)`.
Try to set the: `-fx-background-color` of `.bar-chart:horizontal .chart-bar, .stacked-bar-chart:horizontal .chart-bar` in your css to match the blue you currently have (or another solid color).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for contribution, unfortunately the suggested ways haven't helped.

As for now I found the workaround that's make the chart better, here it is:

`myBarChart.setCategoryGap(-1);`

Hopefully will find the solution later.
[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1chrg.png)